# Running code on program exit in Java

Tags: java, exit-code, system.exit

Is it possible to write a method that System.exit will call when you terminate a program?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use [`Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(Thread)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)).

Answer (score 6):

Shutdown hooks are the answer... [here is an article on them](http://java.dzone.com/articles/know-jvm-series-2-shutdown).  They do not come without issues (some of them are discussed in the article).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a shutdown hook.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)

Note that shutdown hooks will not run if the VM aborts abnormally or Runtime.halt(int) is called.

Comment: Then, What to do In the Case of call to Runtime.halt(int) or abnormally aborts

Comment: @guru_001 Nothing can be done, the VM halts abruptly similar to if it had crashed.

Answer (score 2):

Look into shutdown hooks, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/hook-design.html

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [VM shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).